# How to use redis sentinel to get configuration of current master?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-sentinel

I have configured Redis servers with 1 master and 2 salves and 1 sentinel to monitor the master.
As per the documentation if the master is down sentinel will promote any of the slave as the master.
So my question is how to get the configuration of the replaced master using the c# code via sentinel???
thank you in advance....